# Question about SecurityPanel

Tags: apache-flex, security, panel, privacy

In my app I am using microphone so I use Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY); at launch. In this pop-up box there is a check box 'remember' - how can I get access to the value of this checkbox in my code? The window pop-ups every time i go to the page(State) when I launch Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY) and it seems to remember the settings but it still pop-ups which I don't want. How can I check the value of that checkbox?

Comment: Stop writing tags in titles please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
how can I get access to the value of this checkbox in my code?
```

You can't!  You probably don't need to manually launch the settings thing.  Just access the microphone when needed and that box will pop up automatically.

That approach would be consistent w/ how Adobe Connect does it.

Comment: But when the pop-up is automatic there is no 'remember' checkbox so each time it would appear which is annoying. I figured out to check if Microphone.muted and it works. The problem is when user click 'record' button, the pop up appears, he checks everything but after closing the window he needs to click the button again :/ bummer :/

Comment: The best I can offer you on this one is to provide instructions to users on how to make the pop up go away.  "Bring up context menu, select settings, etc.."